# Null Values in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, splice, array-splice

I am creating objects when textbox having some values (using ng-blur and `textbox.value!==undefined`) and then putting these objects in an array (all working fine here).

When I click on checkbox (checkbox model bind with textbox ng-required) I need to delete that particular object having that textbox value.
I am using:

```
arr.splice(index,1);
```

to remove that particular object from array (by matching it's name like "monthly" or "quarterly" etc.), but it is creating `null` at that particular position.

for e.g. [object,object,object]

```
[
{name:"monthly",
  amount:1000 },

{name:"quarterly",
  amount:1200 },

{name:"yearly",
  amount:1300 }
]
```

after removing all element it shows `[]` and when I add another new object it displays `[3:object]` and it's content as `[null,null,null,object];`

or

if I remove middle object say `name:"quarterly",` it shows `[object,object]` but after adding a new object it display array as `[object,object,null,object]` with length of array as 4.

Why is there `null` and how can I remove that from array. (don't want to iterate again to check `null`).

Comment: Show us the code (plunkr preferably). Splice doesn't have that effect .

Comment: How are you adding the new objects to the array? Would be the best if you add a snippet with all the relevant code.

Comment: are you using loadash or underscore?

Comment: how are u adding element?

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to say **why** your code creates the null values without have a look to it.

But I can say you that **it is not** the expected behaviour.

You can see this example to get some inspiration:

```js
var data = [
{name:"monthly",
  amount:1000 },

{name:"quarterly",
  amount:1200 },

{name:"yearly",
  amount:1300 }
];

var newObjectToBeAdded = { name: "daily", amount:"100" }

function showObjects()
{
     document.body.innerHTML += data + '<hr>';
}

function deleteObjectByName( objectName )
{
    for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ )
    {
     if( data[ i ].name == objectName )
        {
             data.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}

function addObjectToData( newObject )
{
    data.push( newObject );
}

showObjects();
deleteObjectByName( "quarterly" );
showObjects();
addObjectToData( newObjectToBeAdded );
showObjects();
```

Just to throw a guess out, maybe you are accidentally duplicating the array. Maybe in some point of your code you are doing something like this:

```
var new_array = original_array.splice( index );
```

Or creating the new array in the loop you use to find the target object, or using some kind of intermediate array, etc.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

```
var arrayWithoutNulls = myArray.filter(function(val) {
    if (val) {
        return val;
    }
});
```

Comment: If that was suitable, then the callback need only be: `function(val){return !!val}`.